# Eclipse never opening unless reinstalled

Tags: eclipse

So whenever I press on the eclipse.exe it opens and shows the title but it stays there frozen with no loading screen. The only way I can get it to open is when I reinstall it.

I'm using eclipse for C/C++ on windows 11

Comment: What have you downloaded and installed it in which way where?

Comment: I downloaded eclipse from their website and i got an installer which I used to get it. I have to keep using that installer and reinstalling to be able to open it since the normal .exe never opens it.

Comment: Download link? What did you select in the Eclipse installer? Which installation directory did you choose? Which permissions does this directory have?